# How can update multiple fields in RedisJson

Tags: redis, jedis, redisjson

I want to update multiple fields on redis with RedisJSON feature, by using Jedis java client;

[Refrence](https://redis.io/docs/stack/use-cases/#json)

Suppose we have a key:value like below in redis:

`PERSON_1:{name=ali2, phone=1234, address=Tehran, education={uniName=Amirkabir}}`

then we want to update `phone` and `address` fields.

But it seems we can just update only one path or multiple paths with the same field name at a time.

Like:`JSON.GET PERSON_1 $phone 9876`

If we accept that we can only update one field at a time, than we have to hit the redis twice for two fields.

Is there any way to update multiple fields at a time to keep atomicity and have better performance?

I tried to use Jedis like:
`client.jsonSet("PERSIN_1", Path.of("phone"), "9876");`

and

`client.jsonSet("PERSIN_1", Path.of("address"), "Shiraz");`

In this way, we hit the Redis sever twice.

Answer (score 2):

There is a JSON.MSET command in the works. Until then you have a few options.

If you just want atomicity, you can use MULTI and EXEC to do it all in a [transaction](https://redis.io/docs/manual/transactions/). You'll want to WATCH the key first to make sure that no one else has changed it. Like this:

```bash
127.0.0.1:6379> WATCH foo
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> MULTI
OK
127.0.0.1:6379(TX)> JSON.SET foo $ '{ "alfa": "one" }'
QUEUED
127.0.0.1:6379(TX)> JSON.SET foo $.bravo '"two"'
QUEUED
127.0.0.1:6379(TX)> EXEC
1) OK
2) OK
127.0.0.1:6379> JSON.GET foo
"{\"alfa\":\"one\",\"bravo\":\"two\"}"
```

If someone changes `foo` before `EXEC` is called, you'll get an error and then can try again.

You can also do these changes using [pipelining](https://redis.io/docs/manual/pipelining/) to avoid multiple round trips. This just basically shoves all the commands down a socket without waiting for a response.

Jedis supports this but—full disclosure—I've never used pipelining from Jedis before. The [docs](https://github.com/redis/jedis/wiki/AdvancedUsage#pipelining) make it look pretty straightforward though:

```java
Pipeline p = jedis.pipelined();
p.jsonSet("foo", "{ \"alfa\": \"one\" }");
p.jsonSet("foo", "$.bravo", "{ \"alfa\": \"one\" }");
p.sync();
```

If you want to get extra fancy—and who doesn't wanna get extra fancy—you can combine these and use pipelining *with* transactions.

Hope this helps and good luck!

Comment: `p.jsonSet`, not `client.jsonSet`

Comment: Classic copy pasta error on my part! Thanks for catching it. Update and fixed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Jedis' [Transaction](https://javadoc.io/doc/redis.clients/jedis/latest/redis/clients/jedis/Transaction.html). It will be atomic and have better performance<sup>[1]</sup>.

[1] Performance will be better when there are *many* commands, compared to a few commands.

Answer (score 1):

A [`JSON.MERGE`](https://github.com/RedisJSON/RedisJSON/pull/916) command is planned to be available soon, which would also allow to do multiple updates on the same key,

And also, as mentioned by [Guy Royse](https://stackoverflow.com/users/513710/guy-royse), a [`JSON.MSET`](https://github.com/RedisJSON/RedisJSON/pull/944) command is planned, which would allow to do multiple updates on one or more keys.